# Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A^{k})$ for every $k\geq1$ if and only if there exists $m\geq2$ such that $A^{m}=A$

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

> Let $M\left(X\right)=\left\{X^{k}\mid k\in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ for every $n×n$ matrix $X$ with complex entries. If $A$ is an $n×n$ matrix with complex entries and $M\left(A\right)$ is finite, show that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(A^{k})$ for every $k\geq1$ if and only if there exists $m\geq2$ such that $A^{m}=A$.

Since $M\left(A\right)$ is finite we have $A^{r}=A^{s}$ with $r<s$ and $s,r$ are minimal. If $t=s-r$ then $A^{r}(A^{t}-I)=0$. From that the minimal polynomial is $x^{r}q(x)$, where $q(x)|x^{t}-1$.

I tried to apply Sylvester Inequality on $A^{r}(A^{t}-I)$ and we get $n \ge \operatorname{rank}(A^{r})+\operatorname{rank}(A^{t}-I)$. If we want to solve for the direct case we know $\operatorname{rank}(A^{r})=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and we get $n \ge \operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(A^{t}-I)$.

From here I dont know how to continue. Maybe we should write $A=PQ$, where $P$ is $(n×l)$ and $Q$ is $(l×n)$ and $l=\operatorname{rank}(A)$? (PS: The idea with the minimal polynomial is from the previous question and it is Zerox's idea).

Comment: If you have covered Jordan decomposition this could go as follows. The equation $A^r=A^s$ implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are either zero or roots of unity. But $rank(A)=rank(A^2)$ implies that the eigenvalue zero cannot appear in a Jordan block of size $\ge2$. And the finiteness of $M(A)$ implies the same about the non-zero eigenvalues. Therefore we can conclude that $A$ is diagonalizable. The problem is thus reduced to the case of a diagonal $A$ with non-zero entries roots of unity.

Comment: (cont'd)  The claim is then a consequence of the existence of a solutions of the system of congruences $m\equiv 1\pmod {\ell_i}$ being equivalent to $m\equiv1\pmod{\ell}$ with $\ell$ the least common multiple of the orders of those roots of unity.

Comment: But, may be you haven't covered Jordan decomposition. And resorting to them feels a bit too heavy :-/

Comment: Necessity of the rank condition should be immediate.  For sufficiency, hint: consider the equality conditions of $\text{rank}\big(A^{r+1}\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(A^{r}\big)$ and the existence of a left inverse on $A\cdot V$ (i.e. column space / image of $A$).  It's worth also considering this problem when working over a finite field.

Comment: @user8675309 can you explain more please?

Comment: Do you know how to prove $\text{rank}\big(AB\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(A\big)$ and what the equality conditions are?  If yes, then I can fill in a few more details.  If no, I suggest you do that as an exercise first and then revert.

Comment: @user8675309 I know with block matrix transformations.

Comment: I don't know what your response "I know with block matrix transformations" means.  The inequality here has nothing to do with block matrices and everything to do with the fact that $(AB)$ lives in the column space of $A$.  If you're able to prove something like Sylvester Inequality then you should definitely be able to prove this.

Comment: @user8675309  Yes we can prove Sylvester inequality with elementary transformations on block matrices

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, can you explain more your solution? I still struggle with this problem...